# Disabling Scrolling on NIPagingScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, nimbus-ios

i am using Nimbus kit for my app. I have different Page Scroll Views. Each Page have a button. when i click on the button i need to go to next page. for that i am using 
 `[self.pagingScrollView moveToNextAnimated:YES];` . It works fine. But i need to disable to horizontal scrolling of a page. NIPagingScrollView is a subclass of UIView, so i can't use a scrollEnabled property. How can i dsiable scrolling on NIPagingScrollView. I don't want a user to swipe next/previous of the screen.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can access the paging scroll view via the `pagingScrollView` property on NIPagingScrollView.